# Google App Engine 1.8.8 Access to Dev Server on Local Network

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running GAE 1.8.8 with Java. Previously (with GAE v1.7.x a while ago) I have been able to make dev server available over my LAN using `--address=0.0.0.0` flag, as per the docs. So in my case I'd access it on another computer using `http://192.163.0.3:8888/whatever`

I am finding now that I this doesn't work - I get a server unavailable error or 'This page cannot be loaded via this proxy', depending on the computer/device. I am wondering whether this is an issue with my LAN or whether something changed in GAE. I have scoured GAE docs, Google and Stack Overflow but seems that the `--address` flag should still apply.

Has anyone tried this flag successfully on 1.8.8? (or 1.8.7)?